# How do I enter a Portugal address into a Garmin Satnav?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, maps, portugal, gps-navigation

The address is:

Encosta Cabo Girao
Quinta Girao
Empreendimentos Turisticos
Lda. Estrada 1 de Julho nú 2
9300 - 081 CÀmara de Lobos
Madeira, Portugal

When I enter the postcode that I assume is "9300 - 081", the Garmin then demands a road name but will not accept anythink that is in the address.

Answer (score 6):

Using postcodes to reach specific fine-gained locations on a map works in some European countries (the UK for example) but does not work in most since the granularity varies considerably (in Italy postcodes identify neighborhoods, in France they identify municipalities, etc.). Hence your best bet is to enter the city and road. In your case:

- City: Câmara de Lobos
- Road: Estrada 1 de Julho
- House Number: 2

Comment: I had a similar issue with Garmin in Italy and used GPS coordinates successfully; for OP's address they are Latitude: 32.658387 | Longitude: -17.003885